# django admin actions export to csv separate response

Tags: python, django, csv, django-admin, httpresponse

> these tables:
>
> a) HEADER
>
> b) ROWS

are managed from admin, from a) model I've added an action that get the rows referenced in b), it works fine when applied to one object in a).
But selecting multiple objects in a) turns out in a single csv file.
How can I split multiple response to multiple csv, one file for each object with inside all rows referred to it?

```
import csv
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

def export_su_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):

for u in queryset:   # process each selected row to separate responses
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    a=Rows.objects.filter(ref=u)    

    response['Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename={}'.format(u)   
    writer = csv.writer(response)        
    for o in a:             # for single row in rows
        writer.writerow([
            smart_str(o.field1),
            smart_str(o.field2),
            smart_str(o.field3),
        ])

return response
```

Would it be possible to return multiple response? if yes how?
I've tried to write a list of response and return that, but result i s empty.